# When is it acceptable to answer one's own question?

Tags: discussion

When I asked [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/1669/159), I initially provided a few answers of my own. Rather than mention some games that we play in the question itself, I decided to post them as answers. I think referring to specific games in the question would discourage people from providing those answers; however, I thought those games were good options and should be voted on.  This was questioned so I decided to remove my answers pending further discussion.

I'm not sure if my question should be made community wiki or not. It seems to me like it probably should, but I find the CW criteria pretty vague now. However, that's not what I want to focus on here. The debate over subjective questions and CW has been had elsewhere. I'd like this to focus on answering one's own question.

I agree with the general sentiments expressed [here](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270/asking-a-question-you-already-know-the-answer-to-or-padding-out-the-site-with-q) in that I generally don't ask questions I know the answer to and, if I do, I wait a while before providing my own answer. However, that is my personal preference and I don't know if I would want to make that a rule. I think every member of the community has the right to answer any question, even questions they asked. In general, it may not be advisable to do so right away in that it may discourage others from answering and may result in the question and answer not being upvoted much, but that's at the discretion of the questioner, IMO. However, I think that mostly goes for objective questions. I'm not sure it's as much an issue for subjective ones.

So, is answering one's own question right away discouraged? Or, is it just a bad idea from the standpoint of earning rep? Does it make a difference if the question is subjective?

Comment: I think you are right in that recommendation questions are a different situation than the previously linked meta question.  As such, I'm going to defer trying to answer this until we sort out how to address recommendation questions in general

Comment: Concur with Pat; recommendation questions are a completely different case to all-other-questions.  Answers to this should treat them as two separate cases until we've figured out what to do about recommendation questions.

Answer (score 2):

I would make one observation: This community has a "self-learned" badge for anyone that answers their own question with three upvotes of more. That suggests to me that answering one's own question is allowed, if not encouraged. As long as one is genuinely learning (and perhaps educating others), it seems okay.

I have answered my own question from time to time. It's not something I like to do, because I'm here to learn things from others or to become more clear on a point. In one case, I started an answer to my own question as a "prompt" to provoke answers from others. But usually, it means I'm dissatisfied with the answers I've received. Thus, it indicates something like "hey, I think that I can do better." But as a former boss would say, "That's even if better isn't very good."

That's not a preferred option. But it (probably) ought to be an option.